# Not getting parent id to proceed child records in lightning salesforce

Tags: lightning-apps

I want to show all the contacts related to any account onclick of custom button.i am trying to get this but i am getting all the contacts of my org.Please help me solve it.
my code is below-

```
<aura:component controller="HomeApexController" >
<aura:handler action="{!c.NewAccountButton}" name="init" value="{!this}"/>
 <table class="table">
       <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
           <th>Phone</th>
           <th>Id</th>
           <th>*</th>
           </tr>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Acc}" var="Acc">
    <tr>    
           <td>{!Acc.Name}</td>
           <td>{!Acc.Phone}</td>
           <td>{!Acc.Id}</td>
        <td><ui:button label="Go" press="{!c.proceed}"/></td>
           </tr>
</aura:iteration>
       </thead>
      </table>
```

js controller:

```
({
    NewAccountButton : function(component, event, helper) {
        var var1=component.get("c.AccList");
        var1.setCallback(this,function(op){
        var state=op.getState();
        if(state==="SUCCESS"){
        component.set("v.Acc",op.getReturnValue());
        }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(var1);
        },
    proceed : function(component,event,helper){
        var var2 = component.get("c.ConList");
        var2.setCallback(this,function(op1){
        var state=op1.getState();
        if(state==="SUCCESS"){
        component.set("v.con",op1.getReturnValue());   
        }            
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(var2);
    }
})
```

Apex Controller:

```
public class HomeApexController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<Account> AccList(id acctId){
        list<Account> Alist=[select Name,id,Phone from Account];
        return Alist;
    }
        @AuraEnabled
    public static list<Contact> ConList(){
        list<Account> Alist=[select Name,id,Phone from Account];
        return[select id,LastName,phone from Contact where Contact.AccountId IN:Alist];
    }
```

Application:

```
<aura:application >
    <link href='/resource/newbootstrap/' rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Grand Child Relation</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                 <c:grandChild />
            </div>
         </div>
 </aura:application>
```

Comment: You have no "where" condition in your queries. This means you're asking the database for every record of that type in your org.

Comment: No Where condition for his Account Query. He has a WHERE for his Contact query, but he's still querying all accounts first.

Answer (score 1):

In the WHERE clause of Contact query use AccountId of selected Account instead of Ids of all accounts.
 Currently your query is returning all the Contacts related to every Account record in your org.